# Google Chrome: How to debug random "Maximum call stack size exceeded" errors

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In a complex JavaScript app (with jQuery and Ember), the JavaScript will occasionally **crash randomly**, either during page load or when I perform an action on the page. The error is as follows ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RB2Z9.png)):

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
  Class.proto
  Class.proto
  ...
```

... with several pages of `Class.proto` stack trace lines, but no source/line information whatsoever, even at the bottom of the trace.

I know that this points at infinite recursion, and this could conceivably happen in the event system, but there is no obvious starting point for me.

I've been able to reproduce this **only in Chrome Canary** (22.0.1209.0), not Chrome stable or Firefox. The app is not talking to any external service or making any Ajax requests.

Since it happens only occasionally, and with no discernible cause, and since there's no usable stack trace, I'm having trouble tracking down the cause.

**My question:** What can I do to debug this problem?

Comment: You probably already considered this, but as this is only happening in the Canary build could it be a Canary bug? Have you tried the beta or dev chrome builds to see if the problem happens there?

Comment: You could identify the problematic function in the profiler. It must be the longest piece.

Comment: A high chance it's a Canary bug.

Comment: Enable 'Break on exceptions' (This icon https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints-files/pauseOnUncaughtExceptionsButton.png)

Comment: @SplitYourInfinity "Pause on exceptions" doesn't work for me (it doesn't pause, it just throws the error and stops); I'm using the latest release of Chrome.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Enable 'Break on exceptions' in the Chrome Developer Toolbar. Use this [image: This is the icon] icon in the footer of the toolbar on the **Sources** tab (there are 3 states!)

It should stop your code and you can see the stack!

Comment: Great idea, thanks! Funnily enough, Chrome refuses to pinpoint it to any source line. "Break on uncaught" doesn't actually break on the "Uncaught RangeError", and with "break on all" I haven't even been able to reproduce the crash. So that points at a problem in Chrome. Informed sources tell me there's a bug in V8 (in Canary and dev) that's causing this, and there's already a fix, just waiting to be released. So I'll leave this issue be and test my app on Chrome stable for now.

Comment: I just recently encountered quite a complicated stack overflow crash in the react-native packager. The thing which helps is passing:
--stack_trace_limit=32 as default stack size displayed in debugger is too low :(

Comment: @SergeyDryganets where do you pass that value?

Comment: @Birowsky, this is a node argument. One of the V8 config options. You could get a full list by running ```node --v8-options```

Comment: You might try out the ideas described here for browser:
https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack%20Trace%20API

Comment: As of chrome 75 (year 2019) "break on exceptions" doesn't work in this particular type of exception (or, at least on my code). This answer should no longer be the accepted one.

Comment: @IvanCastellanos Thanks for reporting. My assumption is that this is a regression in the developer tools. I created a bug report with the chromium team (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=997469&q=pause%20on%20exceptions&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&sort=-id)
Let's not downvote this answer yet. Instead vote for my ticket to get it fixed. Thanks!

Comment: The bug report didn't quite work (was reverted and left closed). However, I've had some success with their recommendation: `Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity`

Answer (score 2):

Some browsers no longer have breakpoints for uncaught `Maximum call stack size exceeded` errors.

Thanks to [@Split Your Infinity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893502/split-your-infinity) and others on the Chromium [bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=997469&q=pause%20on%20exceptions&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified&sort=-id), there is a decent debugging strategy for Chrome:

```js
Error.stackTraceLimit = Infinity
```

Documented here: https://v8.dev/docs/stack-trace-api