# Debugging "Maximum call stack size exceeded” in production

Tags: javascript, debugging, web, production-environment

I'm using a error tracker to catch any client-side errors. Sometimes I get "Maximum call stack size exceeded" errors, which I'm not able to reproduce (then it would be easy).

The problem is that since this bubbles up to window.onerror I have no idea where or why the error occurred. Any ideas how to catch the real problem?

Comment: Check for any subscriptions to window error event.

Comment: You need to capture the call stack, so you can see what function is recursing infinitely. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687410/when-will-proper-stack-traces-be-provided-on-window-onerror-function

Comment: Daniel, what do you mean with subscriptions?

Comment: Barmar, I can not wrap each function of my whole library inside a try-catch, this slows don't the speed incredibly.

Comment: Answer to this question may be helpful: [Google Chrome: How to debug random “Maximum call stack size exceeded” errors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544321/google-chrome-how-to-debug-random-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-errors)

Comment: They describe the same issue, but don't have a solution either.